# Why is my rendered low-poly object so blobby? It's rendering with polygons that aren't in the model

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, polycount

I'm not just new to Blender, this is actually my first Blender project that was good enough to try to render. Unfortunately, the render went poorly.

I'm on a fairly new M1 Mac Mini. I used GPU rendering, in Cycles. (Also tried it with CPU rendering, same result.)

Here's my car as it looked in the working viewport (Object Mode, I think):

[image: My car as it looked in working viewport]

And here's how it looked when rendered:

[image: My car as rendered]

The body doesn't have nearly as many faces as seem to be rendering. Here's a wireframe. (Looks like I could afford to simplify the bevels on the tires.):

[image: Wireframe view]

The car body seems to be the only messed-up part of the render. I built it from a Cube mesh, extruding parts, insetting parts...nothing fancy. (I can't do fancy.)

Again, it's my first time rendering anything, so maybe this is a common error I'm just seeing for the first time.

I can provide more info about the object and the render settings if it will help. I'm not sure how much or what to include.

Have I accidentally applied a modifier or filter to the car body? If anyone has a clue, please tell me!

Comment: Most likely, you have a subdivision modifier. By default, its subdivision levels are different for viewport and rendering. Check that.

Comment: I think I found it. I'm not sure how it happened, but the material ("black tires") I used for the tires was also applied to the cube, along with the intended materials ("orange" and "glass").
I'm not sure what kind of crazy selection I had going that could apply a material invisibly (or without me noticing), but there it was. I removed it from the car body cube and it fixed the problem.

I guess this will be the answer unless someone has a more complete one, but if someone knows how I was able to assign that material to the cube by accident, lease tell me.

Comment: when you join objects, the modifiers of the active object will be applied to all joined parts (and you'll loose the modifiers of the non active parts).